# Error while reading JSON file in Rust using BufReader: the trait bound Result: std::io::Read is not satisfied

Tags: json, file-io, rust

I am trying to read JSON from a file:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;

impl Params {
    pub fn new(raw_opt2: opt::Opt, path: String) -> Self {
        // Open the file in read-only mode with buffer.
        let file = File::open(path);
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        Self {
            opt_raw: raw_opt2,
            module_settings: serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap(),
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src\params.rs:20:37
   |
20 |         let reader = BufReader::new(file);
   |                                     ^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>`
   |
   = note: required by `std::io::BufReader::<R>::new`
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [File::open](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) operation returns a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html) - signifying that the open operation could succeed or fail.

This is one standout feature of Rust compared to many other languages; it tries to force you to deal with errors. Instead of:

- C - just returns an int
- Python - exceptions (try: finally:)
- C++ - exceptions (needs a libstdc++ runtime)

As you can expect, this leads to more programming time at the start, but overall *much* less hassles and higher quality programs.

After the line `let file = File::open(path);` you have to deal with the result.

If you don't care, and want to crash the program if the file can't be opened:

```
let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
```

To make a better error message in the crash:

```
let file = File::open(path).expect("Unable to open file");
```

To do it properly - [read the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)

Most likely, you'll want to return a `Result` yourself from your function. Then you could rewrite it something like this (to use a [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html)):

```
impl Params {
    pub fn new(raw_opt2: opt::Opt, path: String) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
        // Open the file in read-only mode with buffer.
        match File::open(path) {
            Ok(file) => {
                let reader = BufReader::new(file);
                Ok(Self {
                    opt_raw: raw_opt2,
                    module_settings: serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap(),
                })
            }
            Err(err) => Err(err),
        }
    }
}
```

.. or a more functional way:

```
impl Params {
    pub fn new(raw_opt2: opt::Opt, path: String) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
        // Open the file in read-only mode with buffer.
        File::open(path).map(|file| {
            let reader = BufReader::new(file);
            Self {
                opt_raw: raw_opt2,
                module_settings: serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap(),
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### Update:

Now I generally use these two libraries for error management:

- [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) When I'm writing libraries and creating my own error types
- [anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) When writing applications or scripts or tests to easily handle all the library errors.

.. and of course I didn't mention [the ? operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html), which makes working with results and options so much easier.